# Using an if statement to modify data in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have data that looks like this:

```
Person Change
1       10 
2       0.5
3       -0.25
4       5
5       -20
```

I want to say that if Change < 1, then multiply the number in this column by 100. The results I am expecting to see are.

```
Person Change
1       10 
2       50
3       -25
4       5
5       -20
```

I have tried an if formula saying

```
if(df$Change <1 && df$Change > 0 {
df$Change*100
}
```

This runs fine but does not make any changes to the data and I am unsure of what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ifelse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) with checking if the absolute value of `Change` ([`abs()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/MathFun.html)) is lower than `1`:

```r
df$Change <- ifelse(abs(df$Change) < 1, df$Change * 100, df$Change)

df
#>   Person Change
#> 1      1     10
#> 2      2     50
#> 3      3    -25
#> 4      4      5
#> 5      5    -20
```

Or using a condition as an index:

```r
df_condition = abs(df$Change) < 1
df$Change[df_condition] <- df$Change[df_condition] * 100

df
#>   Person Change
#> 1      1     10
#> 2      2     50
#> 3      3    -25
#> 4      4      5
#> 5      5    -20
```

Or using [`replace()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/replace.html):

```r
df_condition = abs(df$Change) < 1
df$Change <- replace(df$Change, df_condition, df$Change[df_condition] * 100)

df
#>   Person Change
#> 1      1     10
#> 2      2     50
#> 3      3    -25
#> 4      4      5
#> 5      5    -20
```

#### Benchmark

It seems that the condition is the fastest solution, then `replace()` and then `ifelse()`:

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr  min   lq    mean median   uq   max neval
    ifelse 25.9 28.7 29.9806  29.60 30.7  67.2  1000
 condition 20.6 22.7 23.7826  23.60 24.5  48.6  1000
   replace 21.3 23.5 24.7224  24.35 25.3 129.4  1000
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Person = 1:5, Change = c(10, 0.5, -0.25, 5, -20
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing your dataframe to a data table you could use the following easy solution.

You will have to install and import the data.table package

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[ abs(change) < 1 , change := change*100 ]
```